# Woocommerce : add to cart & notice wrapper

Tags: php, woocommerce, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

I'm experiencing difficulties with the "add to cart" button on my product page.

When a customer clicks it, a woocommerce notice appears, which causes my mini cart to be unclickable, my carousel widget to lose its sticky and clickable feature, and creates extra space between my description and image.

Clicking on the mini cart adds a "#" to the website address, as if there is no link.

It seems that clicking "add to cart" loads a different version of the same page, and I'm not sure where to begin to fix this issue.

I'm using Woocommerce, Astra Pro, and Elementor Pro, and I'm aware of the option to hide the notice with a function in function.php, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Thx all!

(My website : https://soapologie.fr)

Tried to hide the notice wrapper with a function in my function.php. Doesn't work.

Comment: Your product pages such as https://soapologie.fr/produit/coffret-decouverte/ throw an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` on load already ... So I would suggest you go and investigate that first of all, because it is likely such an error breaks following JavaScript functionality on the rest of the page.

Comment: _"Clicking on the mini cart adds a "#" to the website address, as if there is no link."_ - the link only has `href="#"`, _because_ it is not supposed to link anywhere, but only trigger JavaScript functionality - that of showing the mini cart overlay within the current page. But you can't expect that to work, when severe errors in your JS already occurred earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will investigate and see why I'm having such error. That's really weird because I'm using Astra + Elementor, they usually work great together.